# Problem with $_GET and fopen

Tags: php

I have a weird problem with `$_GET` method. I have a php code like this:

```
$fopen("files/" . $_GET['file'], "r");
```

When i write file path parameter my self It's run good but when I get the file name from $_GET method it shows me some error like the path is wrong.

1. What's wrong with it ?
2. Is there any special encoding for `$_GET` method to decode it to the right string        style. I tried urldecode but it wasn't make any change.

Comment: did u try to print what u get?

Comment: (a) What URL are you using to view the page? (b) What does `var_dump($_GET);` show you? Note also that $_GET isn't a method, it's a variable, specifically one of PHP's [Superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php).

Comment: `echo "files/" . $_GET['file'];` and show us result

Comment: First of all, "some error"? What error? "Syntax error" is a substantially different problem than "File not found". In your sample here you wrote `$fopen`, which would surely not work. Does your real code use just `fopen`? What is the value of `$_GET['file']` immediately before that statement executes? (Try echoing it to see what's there.)

Comment: -1 for badly formed question. **don't ask strangers "what's wrong with it"**, they have no idea. While you have a comprehensive explanation in the error message. Or at least post this message here - we aren't mediums here.

Comment: Hi guys. I wrote wrong $fopen, but in my code it's right. Of course I dumped and printed the value everything is right ! The file is there and the path and everything can u think is right but I don't know why It just have problem with $_GET while I entered the path myself it was run right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't EVER use user input without validation, especially not for opening files on the host computer!  I cannot overstate just how dangerous this is.  What if someone entered a GET string with the value '../../../../../etc/password' into your application?

Comment: I gotcha. You're right. I dont know why I did it while I have the stored variables in my database which can used in a way to just get the file id and next... Thanks anyway all of you guys !

Answer (score 3):

Number one rule is to sanitize your input.  Using $_GET like that is just asking for trouble.
Do the right thing.  Put the $_GET value into a variable, verify that it is valid input THEN try to open the file.

Comment: You know, you pointed a good item I'll fix it. By the way, I verified my data and it was truly correct.

Answer (score 2):

As said at the bottom:

1. Try to dump the $_GET with print, print_r or var_dump
2. Try to [sanitize the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)
3. Remove the leading $ in your code (**$**fopen)
4. Test if file exists in the specified directory with if(is_file($path)
5. Isn't the problem caused by file extencion or permissions?

There could be more. It also depends on system you use (Win, Unix, Mac..).

Comment: This should be a comment on the question and not an answer.

Comment: Hi, I realise that but I dont see the add comment button unde the question. Am I blind or ff 4 does not like stackoverflow? :-)

Comment: @Bery Naah. You just haven't enough reputation.

Comment: Yep I found that out in the FAQ :-) But thanks for information.

Comment: @Bery There you go I have +1 so now you can comment! :)

Comment: Thank you very much. This will make things a lot more easier for me :-)

Comment: Yeah everything that u said I'll fixed them before.